# AlertDialog EditText doesn't show a soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, keyboard

When i click on a TextInputEditText, *which is parent of a* `LinearLayout` *added programmatically to an* `AlertDialog`, my keyboard doesn't show (tested on multiple devices)

First I create a new `LinearLayout` and add a new `Spinner` to it.
After the last item on the spinner is selected, i remove the spinner from the `LinearLayout` and add a `TextInputEditText`:

```
layout.removeAllViews();
layout.addView(input);
```

When i click on the `TextInputEditText` it gets *focused* but **no soft keyboard pops up**

> **However** if i add the `TextInputEditText` *directly* as a `View` to the `AlertDialog`, the keyboard pops up and gets displayed correctly.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` has no special entrys.

My full code:

```
private void dialogAddContact() {

    ArrayList<String> mails = new ArrayList<>();

    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    final TextInputEditText input = new TextInputEditText(this);
    final Spinner sp = new Spinner(this);

    layout.addView(sp);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    input.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    [....]

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<>([....]);

    sp.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    sp.setAdapter(adp);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(Tools.LOGTAG, position + " " + totalMails);
            if(position == totalMails - 1){

                /****** Here i remove the spinner and add the input ****/

                layout.removeAllViews();
                layout.addView(input);
            }
        }
        [....]
    });

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(layout, 50, 0, 50, 0)
            [....]
            });

    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**#.** Add focus change listener to your `TextInputEditText` and in `onFocusChange()` show keyboard using `.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)`.

**Required to open keyboard:**

```
final TextInputEditText input = new TextInputEditText(this);

// Keyboard
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

// Auto show keyboard
input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean isFocused) {

        if (isFocused) {
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        } 
    }
});
```

**#.** Use below code to `hide` keyboard when your dialog's `button` pressed.

**Required to hide keyboard:**

```
// Hide keyboard
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem but any given solution did not work, then i use its parent class (i.e. `Dialog`) instead of `AlertDialog`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the keyboard when the dialog opens you can add this after `dialog.show()`:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: The keyboard opens now, but: http://scshot.deepspace.onl/5cdb1978-249b-4221-9a1f-bd5c389ee33b.png

Comment: But it doesn't open?

Comment: But it does open in the background of my alertdialog, it does not get pushed up and i can not click on the keyboard

Comment: I recommend that you create a custom class for your Dialog, I can post another answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```